# Getting layer id of processing step in QGIS graphical modeler for usage within aggregate() function

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-modeler, expression, aggregation

How can I get the `layer name` or `layer id` of the result of an processing algorithm within QGIS graphical modeler, so I can use `aggregate()` function in a later processing step? Is this somehow possible at all?

`aggregate( @layer_name,'collect',$geometry)` cannot work here because `@layer_name` is not related to a specific processing algorithm output. If I try `aggregate( @name_of_processing_step_OUTPUT,'collect',$geometry)` or `aggregate(layer_property( @name_of_processing_step_OUTPUT,'id'),'collect',$geometry)` I get `Cannot find layer with name or ID ''` in preview and just no output when running the model.

Comment: For now not possible, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/379831/107424

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you intend to do is now possible using the [variables that QGIS creates when you add an algorithm to the model](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/469257/88814) in newer QGIS versions. You can now use the variable from a previous processing step, such as `@name_of_processing_step_OUTPUT`:

`aggregate(@name_of_processing_step_OUTPUT,'collect',$geometry)`

---

In your case, the output of `Feature Filter` is a layer and to use it in the expression with `aggregate()`, you have to get the layer's *name*. For this, use the function [`layer_property()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#layer-property).

I created a simple model based on your's: it takes an input (point layer with 100 features), then in the model uses `Feature Filter` to filter `$id < 50` and then **only for the filtered features** (=algorithm output) creates a new string (text) field `id_new` with the aggregated `id` values (just for demonstration purpose).

To do so, in the field calculator algorithm, I set the `Input layer` to `Algorithm Output` and use the output `from algorithm "Feature Filter"`. The expression to use looks like this:

```
array_to_string (
    aggregate (
        layer_property (@Feature_filter_OUTPUT_, 'name'),
        'array_agg',
        "id"
    )
)
```

*Model's Field Calculator Algorithm dialog window:*
[image]

*The Model and attribute tables of input and resulting output layers: after running the model, only the first 49 features ($id<50) are kept and the field `id_new` with aggregated `id` values is added:*
[image]

Comment: @MrXsquared what makes you sure this solution works since 3.26? I tested it with 3.24 and it works. I don't have older QGIS versions at hand, but I can't find any information in QGIS visual changelogs for versions 3.22 + that shows that this was introduced: https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelogs.html. So probably it was possible even before.

Comment: Nothing. Just the comment on your linked answer. I was too lazy to test myself or search for changelogs. But definitely it did not work on older versions back in 2020. If it would have worked why did I ask the question then ;)

Comment: I ask because in your question, you have a variable `@name_of_processing_step_OUTPUT` - so I wonder what this should have been good for if not accessing temporary layers...