# Using QGIS model output in same model as layer in field calculator formula

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-modeler

I am trying to use field calculator within a model. In this formula I want to reference the output (temporary layer) of another step of the same model (output objektfilter_strassen_wege, which is named strassenpolygone_flurstuecke). Since this layer is not loaded in QGIS, I get no result. If I save the correct layer after running through the model and have the model repeated, I get a result. But that's not my goal! I want to get it the first time. I enter the following into the field calculator:

```
aggregate(
 layer:= 'strassenpolygone_flurstuecke',
 aggregate:='concatenate',
 expression:=oid,
 concatenator:=', ',
 filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent))
 )
```

`strassenpolygone_flurstuecke` should be called differently as input, I suspect. So not `layer:=` but something else that suggests that it is a generated output. The second possibility that went through my head was to choose to save the layer `strassenpolygone_flurstuecke` instead of the temporary layer. But even if I do this using the model, I don't get any result.

---

Comment: Have tried this kind of calculations within graphical modeler a lot, but never made it work. A [similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/363067/getting-layer-id-of-processing-step-in-qgis-graphical-modeler-for-usage-within-a) about this is still unanswered. I am afraid the answer is "not possible", but lets hope for the best.

Answer (score 6):

This is currently (QGIS 3.16.1) not possible, see the following comment from https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/30397#issuecomment-505699624 :

> The issue here is that expression functions which operate on map
> layers [...] don't currently have access to any temporary output
> layers created a step in a model. This applies to a lot of functions,
> including aggregates.

Here is another ticket describing your use case which is marked as a duplicate of the ticket linked above:
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/37347

Comment: Hello pathmapper, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I am not looking for an input layer which is an output of another step but for the layer in my formula within the field calculator. The field calculator is part of my geaphical model.

Comment: @Alice123 thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this is currently not possible, see my adapted answer above.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely **can** reference a (temporary) output of an algorithm in a QGIS model in an expression. When you add an algorithm to the model, QGIS automatically create new variables for the output of that algorithm. You can find these variables listed wherever you have the expression string builder inside the model.

The variables are named like the algorithm with the suffix `_OUTPUT_` and the leading `@` that marks a variable, e.g. `@Feature_filter_OUTPUT_`:

[image]

Comment: I wonder why you have an underscore here in the end of the variable name. In my case it is always *algorithm_name_OUTPUT*.

Comment: Is this possibly a version issue? In my case (still 3.22.7) using the [...]_OUTPUT variable in the expression leads to an error. Also, if it has been resolved in a recent release, why is the issue still marked as open here https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/30397?

Comment: Seems to work with 3.26.X or newer!

Comment: The variable appears like this with underscore at the end, I don't know why

Comment: Maybe we should always mention QGIS versions when referencing this issue, to make clear that it only works with newer versions? You could add that to your answer. In 3.22 it definitely did not work, but as you mentioned in the first comment here https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/469259/52808, starting at 3.24 it obviously does.

Answer (score -1):

I came across this post while looking for a solution to a similar problem. You just had to replace the layer name with @layer.

```
aggregate(
 layer:= @layer,
 aggregate:='concatenate',
 expression:=oid,
 concatenator:=', ',
 filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent))
 )
```

Comment: I have a strong feeling this is not an accurate answer. This seems to be assumed to work by the answerer because it works outside the model situation. But since all linked issues concerning this on the official github are still open it is clearly not "fixed".