# Use an attribute value as parameter of next tool in QGIS modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

I am building a model where I need to use an attribute value as parameter in the next tool. I include an illustration that will hopefully make the problem clearer.

[image]

So far I have been unable to extract the attribute value outputed by the `Field Calculator` tool and pass it as parameter of the `Buffer` tool. Does anyone know how to achive this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The poblem here is that the `Field calculator` tool outputs a layer but the calculated attribute values are not exposed as a parameter to be used in subsquent steps of the model.

A way to solve this issue is to use the tool `Basic Statistics for fields`. This tool will take a numeric attribute and extract stastitcal aggregations that can be used as a parameter for the next tool:

[image]

So in this particular case, I simply had to add the `Basic Statistics for fields` tool after the `Field calculator` tool.

Thanks to Nyall Dawnson from North Road for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

If you use the field calculator, you have new variables available if you use `Pre-calculated Value` for the input. Best see the screenshot added: for the parameter you want to set the attribute value outputed by the Field Calculator tool, choose `Pre-calculated Value` and than open the expression editor. You have several context-sensitive variables available like `[algorithm_name]_OUTPUT`, in my case: `Feldrechner_OUTPUT`:

[image: C:\Users\DU\Desktop\alma.png]

Comment: In some cases it is also necessary to set the fieldcalculator as dependency in the buffer tool because a variable is used

Comment: Thank you @Babel. I tried that but it does not work. I also tried variants like enclosing the variable name in single and double quotes but still no success.

Comment: Can you share your project/model?

Comment: @Babel it seems the *_OUTPUT variable refers to the whole layer and cant be used to refer to a value within the attribute table, which is what I need. I am including a model case you want to look at it again: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f3jXuL2hoQgcz7Vr1ewBkkyY1uW5Wbn7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: you can get a feature by id using field calculator... or use some aggregate funcion tu do get a aggregate value from a specified column. Because the layer has 1 feature only get it!

Comment: I can not confirm either that this is a working method...

Comment: I suppose it has do something with this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/379831/99589