# Accessing previous algorithm outputs in QGIS graphical modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, algorithm

I want to extract features by expression in a graphical model in QGIS. I want to use the `overlay_touches()` function to extract features that touch those of another layer.

I manage to do this "statically" by referencing the target layer as a vector layer named *edges_only_carriageways* added to the QGIS project before running the model.

```
"highway" = 'service' AND  overlay_touches('edges_only_carriageways_1eba8a9a_f253_4637_9914_88086f4e954d')
```

However, I want to turn this into a dynamic version by referencing the output of a previous algorithm from the model that holds the same features and attributes as the static layer from the above example. The algorithm is called `non-foot carriageways`. I added this algorithm as a dependency to the new algorithm. Then my approach was to do it like this:

```
"highway" = 'service' AND  overlay_touches(@non-foot_carriageways__OUTPUT)
```

But this does not work. No features are being extracted.

If I am on the wrong track, what is the solution for referencing the temporary output features from a previous algorithm of the graphical model?

Comment: This is currently not possible: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/379831/107424

Comment: OK, thanks for the clear answer. So no chance here to create a fully dynamic graphical model, right? Would a processing script be a good alternative solution where I dynamically create the necessary layer to access it within the expression in the respective following processing step? Or is there a simpler way?